Using of "due to"
Are both of these sentences correct?

We are due to go to the polls next year.
The election is due to occur next year.

I think in the first sentence due is the adjective of "We", that is the subject and expect something, and in the second sentence it is the adjective of "The election" that is expected.
So, is it correct, that we can use "due" for both of them:

The subject that expect something
and also for something that is expected?


Your car will soon be due for a major service. A major service is due at 30,000 miles.

We are due to go to the polls next year = We will go to the polls next year. The election is due to occur next year = The election will occur next year.

Due is defined in sense 3, Collins Dictionary:

Adjective


If something is due at a particular time, it is expected to happen, be done, or arrive at that time.


The first price increases are due to come into force in July.

Applying that to the OP's examples, we have

We are expected to go to the polls next year.
The election is expected to occur next year.

The original posts are fine, with meanings stated above.  The same meaning of due applies to both.

Is "expected" in both of these sentences, an adjective?
